# Shipping Method continue button is not working in Magento 1.8

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I need help on Magento 1.8 Checkout Page. My problem is that "Continue Button" of Shipping Method is not working in Magento 1.8. As i googled and found some solution like to replace

```
    <fieldset><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?></fieldset>
```

into

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?></fieldset>
```

in “/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtm”.

But still its not working. Please suggest me if you have another solution.

[image]

Comment: pls try in some other browser and test it

Comment: Did you check your JS error console?

Answer (score 2):

Go to `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml`

and change line 36:

```
<fieldset>
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

to this

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: in shipping method continue button is working but place order button not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for me

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```